# Serial.parseInt value always goes back to 0

Tags: serial, servo

I am trying to read a value between 1000 and 2000 from my Serial Monitor and use it to drive some motors through ESC.

The code works when I use a potentiometer mapped for 1000-2000. I am now trying to use a Serial Monitor, but the "val" keeps going from the value I enter (between 1000 and 2000) and quickly returns to 0.

Why is this?

Here is the code for reference:

```cpp
#include <Servo.h>//Using servo library to control ESC
Servo esc1; //Creating a servo class with name as esc1
Servo esc2; //Creating a servo class with name as esc2
Servo esc3; //Creating a servo class with name as esc3
Servo esc4; //Creating a servo class with name as esc4
void setup()
{
  esc1.attach(7); //Specify the esc signal pin,Here as D10
  esc2.attach(6); //Specify the esc signal pin,Here as D9
  esc3.attach(5); //Specify the esc signal pin,Here as D8
  esc4.attach(4); //Specify the esc signal pin,Here as D7
  esc1.writeMicroseconds(1000); //initialize the signal to 1000
  esc2.writeMicroseconds(1000); //initialize the signal to 1000
  esc3.writeMicroseconds(1000); //initialize the signal to 1000
  esc4.writeMicroseconds(1000); //initialize the signal to 1000
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  int val; //Creating a variable val
  Serial.println("Input ESC Speed between 1000 and 2000:");
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    val = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(val);
  }//Checks for a character in the serial monitor
  Serial.println(val);
  esc1.writeMicroseconds(val); //using val as the signal to esc
  esc2.writeMicroseconds(val); //using val as the signal to esc
  esc3.writeMicroseconds(val); //using val as the signal to esc
  esc4.writeMicroseconds(val); //using val as the signal to esc
}
```

Comment: you use very annoying comment style in  your code. repeating the same thing over and over only makes the code less readable.

Comment: `quickly returns to 0`  ... how long does it take to return to zero?

Comment: jsotola it takes about a second

Comment: its almost as if Serial.parseInt is not going to my val integer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code will work IF you set the Serial Monitor to "No Line Ending" (OSX 10.6.8. IDE Version 1.0.6.2). parseInt() doesn't like the NL + CR chars.

```
unsigned int val;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("Input ESC Speed between 1000 and 2000:");
  while(Serial.available() > 0){
    val = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  if(val > 0){Serial.println(val);}
  delay(1000);
}
```

There is another way to get the integer value using this code:

```
char inputBuffer[16];
unsigned int val;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("Input ESC Speed between 1000 and 2000:");
  while(Serial.available() > 0){

    // A function that reads characters from the serial port into a buffer.
    Serial.readBytes(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer));

    // Convert string to integer
    // cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/
    val = atoi(inputBuffer);

    // memset clears buffer and updates string length so strlen(inputBuffer) is accurate.
    memset(inputBuffer, 0, sizeof(inputBuffer));
  }
  if(val > 0){Serial.println(val);}
  delay(1000);
}
```

The Binary sketch size is 94 bytes less than the first example using parseInt. The second sketch will work with ANY Serial Monitor Line Ending settings.

Comment: Thank you very much  VE7JRO, care to explain the second one? This one works, the first one not so much...even with the serial monitor set to "No Line Ending"


I think i understand my mistake now, i had int val; in my main program, resetting its value each loop around!!

Comment: Which O/S are you using? I'm wondering if the Serial Monitor behaves differently on different O/Ses. I'm using a very old version of OSX, 10.6.8.

Comment: I've add some comments to the while loop section of the second sketch.

Comment: i am using Windows 7 x64. thanks so much for the comments, very helpful!